# fixed footer with windowsphone 8.1, cordova and jquery mobile not working correctly

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I want to use a fixed footer in my cordova project. I m currently testing my development on a windowsphone 8 device and emulator. I used two different sizes of the emulator and receive two problems (one for each) regarding the positioning.

html code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Error in positioning]

As you can see on the left one the footer is too low - on the right one too high. However, if i right click exactly once within the emulator it looks fine as seen in the following screenshot. If i click another time the positioning is false again ...

[image: Desired Look - after exactly one rightclick]

Anyone an idea why this happens and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems with Windows Phone 8. I didn't manage to fix the problem from the left screenshot in the app with visible status bar, so I set `Fullscreen` to `true` in config.xml

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

After that, I had still issues with bottom menu being placed too high, but only on emulator. Everything was looking fine on physical device.

Comment: Thanks i ll check this later ans mark as correct if it s working

Comment: Working great - as said on physical devices it's fine - on emulator still buggy